# Stream video with open cv in python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

Python version = `3.10.2`

open cv version = `4.5.5.62`

code:

```
import cv2
a = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\21-240p.mp4')

while(True):
    ret, frame = a.read()
    cv2.imshow('show',frame)
    #cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')
    #cv2.destroyWindow('show')
```

errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\asd\imreadwrite2.py", line 5, in
>
> cv2.imshow('show',frame)
>
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-
>
> python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error:
> (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in
>
> function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: what do you think, that `ret` value is for ?

Comment: Trust. exactly dont know! I'm beginner on python programming, how resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an escape character issue. If you'll print your file path you'll get C:-240p.mp4 so just add r before the path (avoids escape characters in strings) and you'll get C:\21-240p.mp4

```py
import cv2
import os

vid_path_bad = 'C:\21-240p.mp4'
print(vid_path_bad)
vid_path = r'C:\21-240p.mp4'  # notice the r
print(vid_path)

if not os.path.exists(vid_path):  # good to always check we can find the file
    print('file {} not found'.format(vid_path))
    exit(-1)

a = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_path)

while (True):
    success, frame = a.read()
    if success:  # frame read successfully
        cv2.imshow('show', frame)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k == ord('q'):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I learned this small code in my course and that runned in enother pc!. In your code i must add os lib in python. However thank you

Comment: thank u gilad thats right.my problem solved but why old code not runned in my computer?

Comment: simply because there is an escape character in the path you gave - [explanation on Wikipedia on escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#:~:text=In%20computing%20and%20telecommunication%2C%20an,a%20particular%20case%20of%20metacharacters.) If you want to make your old code work add the 'r' before the string (ignores escape characters) or add another \ like so 'C:\\21-240p.mp4'